# How can I size these spans so that the pictures don't extend past them?

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu5Y5/1/)

In this HTML/CSS, I am trying to create some containers which will hold some text, a profile picture (which can have different sizes) and name.

CSS

```
#fb_status_10150163932662967{
    background:url(http://www.pixel2life.com/twodded/staff/stu/Tutorials/BrickTexture/bricks_zigzag_texture_6190218.JPG) #C0DEED; padding:20px;
}
#fb_status_10150163932662967 p{
    background:#fff;
    padding:10px 12px 10px 12px;
    margin:0;
    min-height:48px;
    color:#000;
    font-size:18px !important;
    line-height:22px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px
}
#fb_status_10150163932662967 p span.metadata{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:8px;
    padding-top:12px;
    height:40px;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6
}
#fb_status_10150163932662967 p span.metadata span.author{
    line-height:19px
}
#fb_status_10150163932662967 p span.metadata span.author img{
    float:left;
    margin:0 7px 0 0px;
}
#fb_status_10150163932662967 p a {
    color: #0084B4;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#fb_status_10150163932662967 p a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline
}
#fb_status_10150163932662967 p span.embedly_timestamp{
    font-size:12px;
    display:block
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="fb_status_10150163932662967" class="fb_status">
    <p>
        text1
        <span class="metadata">
            <span class="author">
                <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/48898_565722966_3090_t.jpg">
                <strong>
                    Ben
                </strong>
                <br>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        text2
        <span class="metadata">
            <span class="author">
                <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/187486_564261187_2838929_t.jpg">
                <strong>
                    Kirsty
               </strong>
                <br>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        text3
        <span class="metadata">
            <span class="author">
                <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/48898_565722966_3090_t.jpg">
                <strong>
                    Ben
                </strong>
                <br>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

As you can see from the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu5Y5/1/), the profile picture extends past the container. How can I make it so that they are contained fully within the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ben; just wirte `overflow:hidden` in your `p` tag

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/Tu5Y5/7/

Answer (score 0):

increase height

```
#fb_status_10150163932662967 p span.metadata {
    border-top: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or write

```
overflow: hidden; in #fb_status_10150163932662967 p { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding :

```
#fb_status_10150163932662967 p { overflow: auto; }
```

Check it out here :

http://jsfiddle.net/ahmad/5p3fx/2/